# How to introduce white space in following?

Tags: php

The following snippet of PHP code creates `$desc` alright, but I like it to introduce two (2) blank spaces between every `dpItemFeatureList` found as it goes through its iteration.

I can't seem to garner exactly what or where to add a snippet to do this?

```
function get_description($asin){
$url = 'http://www.amazon.com/gp/aw/d/' . $asin . '?d=f&pd=1';
$data = request_data($url);
$desc = '';

if ($data) {
    $dom = new DOMDocument();
    @$dom->loadHTML($data);
    $xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
    if (preg_match('#dpItemFeaturesList#',$data)){
        $k = $xpath->query('//ul[@class="dpItemFeaturesList"]');
        foreach ($k as $c => $tot) {
            $desc .= $tot->nodeValue;
        }
    }
}
return $desc;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the code you have shared [here](http://pastie.org/private/gabwg2bbg8qw1xewui7vw) and consequently having a look at the data that you are processing (a sample of which I have pasted [here](http://sebsauvage.net/paste/?69f46e9fece76c54#XR%20/jSwAV6lxtNjySyQO8V7%20Pn45EA7dY%20EJGSjAXj0=)) you actually want to collect the text within the `<li>` child elements of the `<ul class="dpItemFeaturesList">` node.

In your original code snippet your XPath is as follows:

```
'//ul[@class="dpItemFeaturesList"]'
```

This will only select the `<ul>` element and *not* the child elements. Consequently when you try to do a `$tot->nodeValue` it will concatenate all the text within all it's child nodes *without* spaces (ah ha, the real reason why you want spaces in the first place).

To fix this we should do two things:

1. Select the `<li>` nodes within the appropriate node. Change the XPath to `//ul[@class="dpItemFeaturesList"]/li`.
2. In the `foreach` loop concatenate 2 non-breakable spaces `&nbsp;&nbsp;` (because this is HTML) to the `$desc` variable.

Here `$c` is the array index.

```
function get_description($asin){
    $url = 'http://www.amazon.com/gp/aw/d/' . $asin . '?d=f&pd=1';
    $data = request_data($url);
    $desc = '';

    if ($data) {
        $dom = new DOMDocument();
        @$dom->loadHTML($data);
        $xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
        if (preg_match('#dpItemFeaturesList#',$data)){
            $k = $xpath->query('//ul[@class="dpItemFeaturesList"]/li');
            foreach ($k as $c => $tot) {
                if ($c > 0) {
                    $desc .= "&nbsp;&nbsp;";
                }
                $desc .= $tot->nodeValue;
            }
        }
    }
    return $desc;
}
```

We check for `$c > 0` so that you will *not* get *extra* spaces after the last node in the loop.

P.S.: Unrelated to your original question. The code for which you shared a link has an undefined variable `$timestamp` in `$date = date("format", $timestamp);` on `line 116`.

Comment: Tried but it seems no change in output. Still same result.

Comment: @TimLee Put `var_dump($desc);` before the return. What do you get? Do you have spaces in that output?

Comment: No, I still can't get it. I don't know what's the cause; the code is here at [link](http://pastie.org/private/gabwg2bbg8qw1xewui7vw). Would be extremely grateful if you could advise what is wrong. Thanks.

Comment: @TimLee In the data you are running this on, every `dpItemFeaturesList` actually corresponds to a `<ul>` element. Do you want to place 2 blank spaces after encountering the `<ul>` tag (even after the last instance of `<ul>`)?

Answer (score 0):

Since you're appending everything to desc, try something like

```
$desc .= $tot->nodeValue;
$desc .= "<br />"
```

Comment: This only added a line break at the end of $desc.   Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

try that:

```
$desc .= $tot->nodeValue.'  ';
```

and `trim($desc)` after the loop to avoid two spaces at the end.

or, alternatively create an array:

```
$desc = array();
//....
$desc[] = $tot->nodeValue;
```

and return `implode('  ', $desc)`

Comment: When I tried    $desc .= $tot->nodeValue.'  '; and use &nbsp;&nbsp;

Answer (score 0):

If you need that between each one, you need to add in front on each iteration *but* the first:

```
        $k = $xpath->query('//ul[@class="dpItemFeaturesList"]');
        foreach ($k as $c => $tot) {
            $c && $desc .= '  '; # all but first
            $desc .= $tot->nodeValue;
        }
```

This is an expression which saves you an `if` but it works similar. Maybe a bit of taste so sure, an `if` can do it as well:

```
        $k = $xpath->query('//ul[@class="dpItemFeaturesList"]');
        foreach ($k as $c => $tot) {
            if($c) $desc .= '  '; # all but first
            $desc .= $tot->nodeValue;
        }
```

This works because every integer number but zero is `true` in PHP.

[See the demo](http://eval.in/5732).

Comment: Please provide an ASIN that represents HTML which contains a *dpItemFeaturesList* class.

Comment: Generally speaking, this works: http://eval.in/5732 - No idea what your concrete issue is, probably because you don't provide an ASIN that matches your other conditions?! Just puzzled.

Comment: eg. ASIN B007MW146S. If you look at [link](http://www.amazon.com/ASUS-A53U-AS22-15-6-Inch-Laptop-Mocha/dp/B007MW146S/ref=pd_zg_rss_ts_e_565108_5?ie=UTF8) you will see the 4 bulleted features.  My output shows this string appearing as "AMD Dual Core E-450 Processor 1.65GHz4 GB DIMM RAM500GB 5400rpm Hard Drive15.6-Inch Screen, ATI HD 6320GWindows 7 Home Premium (64-bit)".

Comment: you must have some magic in `request_data` that I do not have here (using `file_get_contents`). for the ASIN you gave me B007MW146S, I do not get that back with the URL you provided. I bet you won't either: http://www.amazon.com/gp/aw/d/B007MW146S?d=f&pd=1 - Please check that you provided the correct code to generate the URI.

Comment: Even when I request that link with my browser and look inside for the text `dpItemFeaturesList` I don't find it in there. You must do something utterly wrong here, at least you are not providing the information you claim to.

Comment: Sorry Hakre if confusing. I try post complete code here but got message saying it's too long.  How do I show code here? (or maybe i looking in wrong place to correct error)?  But how do I show you code?

Comment: In your question. If it's too long for your question, put it as a gist on github or similar. Also please take note that if your code is very long, you might need to just ask in a more clever manner, because I actually can not imagine that your issue is hard to solve. You probably just need to better pinpoint it, e.g. with basic trouble-shooting.

Comment: Sorry I not familiar with github. But I have it here on pastie [link](http://pastie.org/private/gabwg2bbg8qw1xewui7vw).  Does this make sense?  Thanks.